# Can c#/c++ be used for IBM COS API

Tags: c#, c++, ibm-cloud, object-storage, ibm-cloud-platform

Currently looking at IBM cloud storage as an option. Wondering if there is any easy way to talk to it via c#.  Would the Amazon s3 .net SDK work for it?  Or maybe the amazon s3 c++ sdk?

It’s a shame that IBM only officially supports python, java and node sdk

Is there any gotchas if I were to try to leverage the amazon s3 sdk directly

Answer (score -2):

According to the [IBM documentation](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/cloud-object-storage/api-reference/about-api.html#about-the-ibm-cloud-object-storage-api), COS

> supports a subset of the S3 API for easy migration of applications to IBM Cloud.

so, depending on what functions exactly you need you might be able to use the Amazon S3 SDK. If the functions you need turn out to not be supported can probably use [`HTTPClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.7.2) to wrap COS native API endpoints.

Comment: How can I point to IBM when using Amazon SDK? I setup `AWS` at my appsettings.json with Profile and region, but there is no URL or something like that